# How to preserve enum variant in match arm on matched experssion in Rust

Tags: rust, match

I think the problem is best described by an example:

```rust
enum SensitiveVector<T> {
  Empty,
  Filled(Vec<T>),
}

impl<T> for SensitiveVector<T> {
  pub fn append(mut self, other: Self) -> Self {
    match (&self, &other) {
      (Empty, Empty) => Empty,
      (Empty, Filled(_)) => other,
      (Filled(_), Empty) => self,
      (mut vector @ Filled(_), Filled(other_items) => {
        vector.0.append(other_items);
        vector
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to be efficient and not simply clone the vectors or similar, but re-use memory (hopefully) efficiently.
Anyway, the fourth arm of the match expression is my problem. I simply don't know how to append the vector items of the `other` instance to `self` if this arm matches. I tried to apply any syntax I've seen in a match arm, but it always tells me that the type is just `&SensitiveVector<T>`, so accessing the tuple field `0` is not possible.

I know the code is probably horrible. But can anyone tell me how to do such thing? Of course I could just the both vectors and create a new `SensitiveVector` instance, but I thought extending `self` is more efficient.

Thanks for any help and explaining me what syntax/concept/rule I'm missing.

Comment: Actually, creating/cloning etc. empty vectors is pretty cheap already: an empty vector doesn't allocate, it's just a dangling pointer with length and capacity set to zero .

Answer (score 5):

There are some mismatches between values and references.
Since you seem to want to deal with values (consume arguments to emit a new value), I suggest you use values all the way long (especially remove the references in the match statement).

As soon as the match statement destructures `self` or `other`, these two values don't exist anymore, just the destructured members still exist, then you have to recreate an enum from these members (not try to reuse `self` or `other` as a whole).

Here is your example with a few corrections.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum SensitiveVector<T> {
    Empty,
    Filled(Vec<T>),
}

impl<T> SensitiveVector<T> {
    fn append(
        self,
        other: Self,
    ) -> Self {
        match (self, other) {
            (Self::Empty, Self::Empty) => Self::Empty,
            (Self::Empty, Self::Filled(other_items)) => {
                Self::Filled(other_items)
            }
            (Self::Filled(items), Self::Empty) => Self::Filled(items),
            (Self::Filled(mut items), Self::Filled(mut other_items)) => {
                items.append(&mut other_items);
                Self::Filled(items)
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    {
        let sv1 = SensitiveVector::<i32>::Empty;
        let sv2 = SensitiveVector::<i32>::Empty;
        println!("empty and empty: {:?}", sv1.append(sv2));
    }
    {
        let sv1 = SensitiveVector::<i32>::Empty;
        let sv2 = SensitiveVector::Filled(vec![1, 2, 3]);
        println!("empty and filled: {:?}", sv1.append(sv2));
    }
    {
        let sv1 = SensitiveVector::Filled(vec![1, 2, 3]);
        let sv2 = SensitiveVector::<i32>::Empty;
        println!("filled and empty: {:?}", sv1.append(sv2));
    }
    {
        let sv1 = SensitiveVector::Filled(vec![1, 2, 3]);
        let sv2 = SensitiveVector::Filled(vec![4, 5, 6]);
        println!("filled and filled: {:?}", sv1.append(sv2));
    }
}
/*
empty and empty: Empty
empty and filled: Filled([1, 2, 3])
filled and empty: Filled([1, 2, 3])
filled and filled: Filled([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But by always constructing a new enum variant, this means I'm always de-allocating and allocating some memory for this, right? Though the vector inside would just remain where it is on the heap. Correct?

Comment: No, we are not allocating/deallocating anything because we reuse the vector taken from `self` for example to create the result. In terms of bytes it's roughly just a pointer and two integers (the content of the vector is not duplicated). The only reallocation happens when we append one vector to the other if the capacity is exceeded, but that is expected when dealing with a vector.

Comment: @weilbith give the compiler more credit, it [sees a `Filled` is just the same as a `Vec`](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/rcveP7P5d) so all of that just gets optimized away. Don't prematurely optimize your stuff.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much! I'm looking forward to inspect this for some "bigger" cases where the enum variants hold more data. But I guess the compiler is still very smart.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is twofolds:

1. you're matching on `(&self, &other)`, so the values in the pattern are always *shared references*, they can't be owned (returned) and they can't be modified.
2. Enum variants are not types in rust, and rust has no type refinements. So `vector @ Filled(_)` will give you a `vector: SensitiveVector` (at best, here it's an `&SensitiveVector`), you can't access the fields of an enum variant from the enum itself, so the pattern match is largely wasted if your goal is to update the contents.

Since you're taking `self` and `other` by value anyway, the first fix would be to also match them thus, this means you also need to return the value you matched in the second and third arms, or need to reconstruct the values from the contents:

```rust
enum SensitiveVector<T> {
  Empty,
  Filled(Vec<T>),
}
use SensitiveVector::*;

impl<T> SensitiveVector<T> {
  pub fn append(mut self, other: Self) -> Self {
    match (self, other) {
      (Empty, Empty) => Empty,
      (Empty, v @ Filled(_)) => v,
      (v @ Filled(_), Empty) => v,
      (mut vector @ Filled(_), Filled(other_items)) => {
        vector.0.append(other_items);
        vector
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That does not fix the 4th arm, but now instead of using an @-pattern you should just move the inner vector out, merge the vectors, then re-wrap the result:

```rust
enum SensitiveVector<T> {
  Empty,
  Filled(Vec<T>),
}
use SensitiveVector::*;

impl<T> SensitiveVector<T> {
  pub fn append(self, other: Self) -> Self {
    match (self, other) {
      (Empty, Empty) => Empty,
      (Empty, v @ Filled(_)) => v,
      (v @ Filled(_), Empty) => v,
      (Filled(mut v), Filled(ref mut other)) => {
        v.append(other);
        Filled(v)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I was already on the track with the 2nd and 3rd arm, but failed to do the same for the 4th one. So in case of the last arm I must always construct a new instance? 
Assuming the `Filled` variant would be a multi-tuple or a struct, would I always need allocate new memory for this instance and refer to the data of the former instance? Hope that makes sense...

EDIT:

Comment: As I'm still learning what actually happens in memory. So I know that is picky. But in the first arm, would it be more "cheap" to just return one of the both matched values instead of creating a new instance? I guess in case of an empty enum variant, it doesn't matter much. But for other cases?

Comment: No, not at all, the resulting binary will be the exact same @weilbith.

Comment: You could also use or patterns to join cases 2 and 3 to `(Empty, v@Filled(_)) | (v@Filled(_), Empty) => v`

Comment: Interesting. I'll see which code reads better. But in general pretty cool! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Alternatively, change it but return `self`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=864e6e579ac2e4db61a9d354763b3b3f.